# Create custom error message in check constraints in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, check-constraints

I'd like to see the ability to attach custom error messages to CONSTRAINT objects, specifically CHECK constrints. Either directly or via a custom error number in sysmessages.

I've seen developers have to create triggers. I think that's not a good reason to implementing it.

I'm using SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. The only way you could do this would be to have a custom error message and handle the constraint via a trigger, in which you could then raise an error using your custom message

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could name your constraint with a user message.

**For Example:**

```
ADD CONSTRAINT 
[Foo cannot be greater than Bar. Please be sure to check your foos and bars next time.] 
CHECK (foo <= Bar)
```

Comment: While helpful, this still does not allow embedding of variables in a custom message. I would have liked to output the values in the error message that I use in the logic of my check constraint.

Comment: Is it possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old post, but I've found something that may make it a *bit* easier to provide clearer error messages for check constraints to the end-user: the names of check constraints can include carriage returns and line feeds, so the error message can be made a bit easier to see.

E.g. creating the following constraint produces the error message below. (the blank lines between the `[` and `]` are intentional i.e. they are **part of the constraint name**.)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Sales WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [


ERROR:
You have stupidly entered a negative selling price. Please report to detention.


] CHECK ([SellingPrice] >= 0.00)
GO
```

And when this constraint fails, the resulting message is:

[image]

I tried putting markup in the error message (i.e. constraint name), like `<b>message</b>` and `*message*`, but to no avail. And it may be possible, but really unwieldy, to use this for foreign key constraints as well. I haven't tried it.

So it's not a 100% solution, but hopefully easier for the user to see the intended error message.

**Edit** (2022-02-09): Since database object names are stored using the [sysname](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=sysname,names) data type (search for 'sysname' on this page), they cannot be longer than 128 characters. Use short error messages

Comment: That is really ugly abuse of a quoted identifier, but +1 for the atrocious solution :)

Comment: [Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29187.t-sql-error-handling-for-check-constraints.aspx) is an interesting TechNet article about how to create meaningful error messages just in T-SQL. They use a table containing constraint names and error messages. To make it totally seamless though, you have to use a TRY / CATCH block wherever you INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE, and want a meaningful message if a constraint makes it fail. However a similar principle could no doubt be used in front-end code...

Comment: One of the most beautiful ugly hacks I have ever seen.

Comment: This is definitely a most terrible and awesome thing at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly

A CHECK constraint fails with a standard error message. You could use a TRY/CATCH block to parse the error and throw your own (RAISERROR) or use a trigger.

I'd check first so it doesn't fire, either is SQL or in client code. And of course you leave the constraint there to protect data integrity

So if you have a constraint

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_foobar CHECK (@foo <= @Bar)
```

You run the following SQL code or equivalent in your client code:

```
...
IF @foo > @bar
    RAISERROR ('foo (%i) can not be greater than bar (%i)', 16, 1, @foo, @bar)

INSERT MyTable (foo, bar) VALUES (@foo, @bar)
....
```