# Throw exception from SQL Server function to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception

I have stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 say spXample and a scaler-valued function say fXample.
I call a function fXample from spXample.
Can I throw an exception in function and catch it in stored procedure's `Catch` block and rethrow to the calling C# code?

**Update:**

The function I wrote like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fXample(@i INT)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT CASE WHEN @i < 10 
    THEN THROW 51000,'Xample Exception',1;
    ELSE (SELECT @i) 
    END);
END
GO
```

I am getting error

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure fXample, Line 46 Invalid use of
>   a side-effecting operator 'THROW' within a function.

How do I write alternative code to achieve above functionality?

Comment: Throw an exception in the function based on what type of condition? And what type of function, scalar, TVF, multi-statement TVF?

Comment: Try RAISERROR: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx. If you give it a lower severity, it can be caught by a CATCH. From there, you can call it with a "critical" severity (I think 11+; there are examples on the page) and it will stop the SP's execution and kick it back to your application.

Comment: Aaron its scaler-valued, exception would be validation based.

Comment: Haven't got 2012 here to test with but I don't think you can. What happens if you try? On previous versions trying to use `RAISERROR` would fail with `Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'RAISERROR' within a function.`

Comment: @AaronBertrand see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485034/how-to-report-an-error-from-a-sql-server-user-defined-function how to handle this (+1 for pointing how to post such information)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by forcing an error condition when your validation fails, provided that isn't a possible error that might occur naturally. When you know a certain error can only occur when validation has failed, you can handle that in a custom way by checking for that error_number in your catch block. Example in tempdb:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fXample(@i INT)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT CASE WHEN @i < 10 -- change this to your "validation failed" condition
    THEN 1/0         -- something that will generate an error
    ELSE (SELECT @i) -- (you'd have your actual retrieval code here)
    END);
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spXample
  @i INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  BEGIN TRY
    SELECT dbo.fXample(@i);
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 8134 -- divide by zero
    BEGIN
      THROW 50001, 'Your custom error message.', 1;
      -- you can throw any number > 50000 here
    END
    ELSE -- something else went wrong
    BEGIN
      THROW; -- throw original error
    END
  END CATCH
END
GO
```

Now try it out:

```
EXEC dbo.spXample @i = 10;  -- works fine
EXEC dbo.spXample @i = 6;   -- fails validation
EXEC dbo.spXample @i = 256; -- passes validation but overflows return
```

Results:

```
----
10
```

> Msg 50001, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spXample, Line 12
>   Your custom error message.
>
> Msg 220, Level 16, State 2, Procedure spXample, Line 7
>   Arithmetic overflow error for data type tinyint, value = 256.

Comment: Thanks, but what ridiculous hoops we have to jump though to do something which is so simple!
Just shows that SQL is a language of the past which simply isn't moving on. :(

Comment: I'd just like to add THROW is from Sql Server 2012

Comment: @NickG, You could use a stored procedure instead. Functions are actually an elegant way to say that they don't have side effects. Of course, they still do since you can throw a built in error - so it is not entirely true that they don't have side effects. It's an elegant way of having pure functions in a language. SQL is a language well ahead of its time and is pretty impressive considering how old it is. It is basically a DSL for set based data. Pretty amazing!

Answer (score 3):

```
/*  *** EXAMPLES ***
    SELECT dbo.fnDoSomething(500) -- RETURNS TRUE
    
    SELECT dbo.fnDoSomething(5000) -- THROWS ERROR
        Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
        Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 
        'Function Error - [dbo].[fnDoSomething] - Value is greater than 1000' to data type bit.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnDoSomething
(
    @SomeValue      INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @SomeValue > 1000
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @FunctionName AS SYSNAME = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID))
        DECLARE @Error AS VARCHAR(200) = 'Function Error - '+ @FunctionName + ' - Value is greater than 1000'
        RETURN  CONVERT(BIT,@Error)
    END

    RETURN 1
END
GO
```

Comment: I love it! Just as ugly as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33897722/303101)

Answer (score 2):

Although this has been solved but I feel I should still share this. As I think it will be a simpler solution:

```
BEGIN TRY
    THROW 60000, 'Error', 1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW
END CATCH
```

Comment: Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure test, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 57]
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator '**BEGIN TRY**' within a function.
Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure test, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 57]
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator '**THROW**' within a function.
Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure test, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 57]
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator '**END TRY**' within a function.
Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure test, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 57]
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator '**BEGIN CATCH**' within a fun....

Answer (score 1):

You can also raise an error in the stored procedure if a certain condition is met but the error severity has to be higher than 10 to throw an SQL exception

```
CREATE PROC test
AS
RAISERROR('the error message', 11, 1);
RETURN
```

you can access this message later in your catch block as such

```
try {
    testProc.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Output : "the error message"

Comment: From [Microsoft's documentation on RAISEERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql): "The RAISERROR statement does not honor SET XACT_ABORT. New applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR." This question is also about throwing an exception from within a function, not a stored procedure.